Updating User Profile Logs Out User in Django and Does Not Save Changes
I am working on a Django app with two apps: user for profile management and blog for posts. When a logged-in user tries to update their profile, they are unexpectedly logged out, and the changes are not saved. But it is working when it is done from the admin page. I've included the relevant views, models, forms, and settings below.  I am new to django and this is my first project in the same.
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    
    context = {'u_form': u_form, 'p_form': p_form}
    return render(request, 'user/profile.html', context)

models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile' 



forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']

profile.html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}{{ u_form|crispy }}{{ p_form|crispy }}<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button></form>

I tried a few things to fix the issue: I confirmed {% csrf_token %} is in the form template to prevent CSRF issues, checked session settings in settings.py to ensure sessions aren’t expiring early, and added debug print statements to confirm that u_form and p_form are valid and saving correctly. However, I’m still getting logged out, and the profile updates aren’t saved

There is nothing wrong with the code you provided, it works as expected. Make sure you are pointing to the right view and there are no conflicts whatsoever.
